# How can I remove a beeswax finish from a wooden countertop?

Tags: wood

I want to remove the beeswax that has been rubbed into my kitchen countertops and refinish them with with Waterlox tung oil and sealer.  **how do you remove beeswax from countertop?**

Answer (score 1):

Start with a wax stripper chemical such as you would use on floors. Use a "Scotch-brite" pad to assist with removal of old stubborn wax. Dry with rags then clean with mineral spirits. Follow that when dry with a thorough sanding with successively finer grit papers, ending with very fine (600). Then finish as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I've also used a putty knife to gently scrape off the areas where the wax is heaviest. Once the large amounts of residue are gently removed, I've used a wax stripper, scotch bright, and then sand paper. Goof off may work as well but has an odor that is a bit strong.